# Gmod - SWRP (DarkRP) problems

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

So basically I am trying to start a Gmod Server, but when I spawn into my server, I auto-die, unable to open the F4 menu, and unable to respawn.
After researching this problem I figured out it was because my set Default Job in my custom jobs wasn't working correctly. (but haven't found a answer to the problem)
This is the two error messages i'm getting:

```
[ERROR] A runtime error has occurred in "gamemodes/starwarsrp/gamemode/modules/base/sv_gamemode_functions.lua" on line 710.
The best help I can give you is this:

DarkRP was unable to introduce player "RoboOrSomething" to the game. Expect further errors and shit generally being fucked!

Hints:
    - This error most likely does not stand on its own, and previous serverside errors have a very good chance of telling you the cause.
    - Note that errors from another addon could cause this. Specifically when they're thrown during 'PlayerInitialSpawn'.
    - This error can also be caused by some other addon returning a value in 'PlayerInitialSpawn', though that is less likely.
    - Errors in your DarkRP configuration (jobs, shipments, etc.) could also cause this. Earlier errors should tell you when this is the case.

The responsibility for the error above lies with (the authors of) one (or more) of these files:

------- End of Simplerr error -------
```

That one ^ is the first error I get whenever I join the game.

And here's line 708 through 712

```
 function GM:PlayerSpawn(ply)
    if not ply.DarkRPInitialised then
        DarkRP.errorNoHalt(
            string.format("DarkRP was unable to introduce player \"%s\" to the game. Expect further errors and shit generally being fucked!",
                IsValid(ply) and ply:Nick() or "unknown"),
```

This one:

```
function GM:PlayerSpawn(ply)
    if not ply.DarkRPInitialised then
        DarkRP.errorNoHalt(
            string.format("DarkRP was unable to introduce player \"%s\" to the game. Expect further errors and shit generally being fucked!",
                IsValid(ply) and ply:Nick() or "unknown"),
```

is the error I get whenever I press F4 to try to open the F4 menu.
This is a error that is constantly repeating in the console:

```
[ERROR] gamemodes/starwarsrp/gamemode/modules/base/cl_gamemode_functions.lua:23: attempt to index local 'jobTable' (a nil value)
  1. Call - gamemodes/starwarsrp/gamemode/modules/base/cl_gamemode_functions.lua:23
   2. unknown - gamemodes/starwarsrp/gamemode/modules/base/cl_gamemode_functions.lua:62
```

And if anyone wants to ask, yes I have used commands to change my job, but i'm still not able to respawn when I do so.

Comment: You line 710 is `errorNoHalt` ... This is the line that actually is there to let you know there was an error. The actuall error lies somewhere else where the gamemode is initialized (on a per player base). As your line 710 can only be reached when `Player.DarkRPInitialised` is `false`y

Comment: The cause of the error is most likely down to misconfiguration. Such an issue would be highlighted via an error during the server's launch, so keep your eye open for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an config error with your jobs.lua file. Try to run it through [GLuaLinter](https://fptje.github.io/glualint-web/) or just use a generator website that you can find. If that doesn't help, maybe try and reinstall the DarkRP gamemode